# Is the Doctor's inability to backtrack along his own timeline consistent?

Tags: doctor-who, time-travel

In the new *Doctor Who* series, we are frequently reminded that the Doctor "becomes a part of the events" as soon as he enters a time period, and is unable to (or should not) backtrack to fix his mistakes along that series of events.

[image: Doctor Intervention]

The question is (please refer to the diagram):

While he cannot travel back along a series of events of which he is a part (i.e. within the blue rectangle), what prevents him from traveling further into the past beyond those events and leaving a message for himself, or better yet, geting a proxy to help him out? Isn't this what he did in *[Blink](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Blink)*? Why didn't the [reapers](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Reaper) appear then? How do we know when it's just "wibbly wobbly timey wimey" stuff and when it's time for the reapers?

**Edit/Clarification**: In *Blink*, a future Doctor stuck in the past forwards information to the present to get someone to alter his timeline. No more than one copy of the Doctor was present at any given point of the timeline, but the net effect was the same -- alteration. Why was this allowed?

Comment: The diagram is a result of me getting carried away while trying to explain the behavior of time to myself. If the text is unclear (SE has reduced the original image), try: http://i.stack.imgur.com/gTlVw.png

Comment: I like to call the Reapers "paradactyls."

Comment: excellent diagram!

Comment: Not stictly an answer but, he crossed his own timeline with Martha Jones (Martha's first episode, the future Doctor saw Martha on the street just prior to her seeing the present Doctor in the hospital); and he crossed his own timeline with Amy, even interacting with himself (granted the universe was imploding but, in the final episode of the 2010 series, in the museum he went back in time, spoke to himself in front of Amy and Rory and then "died").

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the current show-runner, Stephen Moffat, is on record as saying that nothing in _Doctor Who_ is, or ever will be, or ever has to be, consistent. A story about time-travel means there's no such thing as discontinuity.

Comment: @UncleMikey: It's also worth pointing out the Moffat has in fact demonstrated a strong understanding of paradox and how to avoid it in his writing.  The Doctor generates information paradoxes all the time, but scrupulously avoids observed-event paradoxes - to the extent that in Moffat episodes, apparent continuity errors turn out to be instances of internally consistent time travel.

Comment: The episode "Blink" is a perfect example of when the Doctor has to do something to maintain the timeline as it is. Sally Sparrow hands the folder to pre-Angels Doctor, while he's in the middle of something else. Then he gets Angel'd and reads the folder, which is when he realizes he has to do something to make this chain of events occur, so that Sally Sparrow gets to chat with him from the 60's. He didn't do it so that she would alter his timeline, he did it to maintain the established timeline which resulted in him receiving the folder.

Comment: Sigh, everyone knows the normal course of history is black, the speaker's plans are red, and deviations are blue. Blue for normal and red for deviation [is just plain wrong ;)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychohistory_%28fictional%29#The_Prime_Radiant)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain that sounds oddly similar to the Microsoft Word revision tracking color scheme... Also, 'Seldon Black' sounds like fashion term.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From my understanding the timeline is generally pretty robust, able to change to all of the things the Doctor and others do to it. However, in [Father's Day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Father%27s_Day_%28Doctor_Who%29) they establish that having multiple copies at one location, especially interacting with one another, is enough to "weaken" the timeline and cause serious problems (like spontaneous paradactyl attacks). If he and Rose simply observed the other copy watching instead of interfering their would have been no problem. In fact on several occasions the Doctor refers to times where he has witnessed the same event multiple times.

I don't think its the copies that cause the problem (although they raise the risk greatly) its the interaction of multiple copies (perhaps even through messages) that can cause a problem.

Comment: I've added a clarification to the question...

Comment: I believe the point is interacting with another person to cause the change is far enough removed from him directly impacting himself that the wibly is wobbly enough for it.

Answer (score 6):

The problem isn't in crossing his own timeline, it's creating a paradox by rewriting his own timeline.

For instance, the whole point of the Doctor returning to his own death in the 2011 series is that he had to preserve a sequence of events that already happened -- when he failed to do so, at a fixed point in time no less, it nearly caused time itself to implode around him. Crossing his own timeline in that case was *necessary* to preserve causality.

Comment: This also explains why the adventures with multiple doctors are possible.

Comment: @Blazemonger The first part of your answer is right on target, not so much the second. They don't "go back", that is, don't travel back to that point in time, rather the anomalous timeline ceases to exist and is "rewound" when he and River touch. He never crosses his own timeline in this instance.

Comment: What "anomalous timeline"? There was no other timeline -- when River failed to kill the Doctor, time *stopped* and everything was suddenly happening at once. Time couldn't be "rewound" because it ceased moving forward entirely. Such is the nature of a fixed point.